# Social sharing count for both http and https

Tags: twitter, https, facebook-like, google-plus

I've recently changed a website to SSL (https) and now I have a problem for the social sharing counts (twitter, facebook, and google+) for the articles on the website.

Shared link was like `http://website.com/article` If I change it to `https` I lose the count.

How can make the count works both on http and https?

Answer (score 0):

Pass the http:// address to the social plugin. And redirect http:// addresses to https:// when the link is followed back.

Comment: Facebook is working but twitter is always showing zero count when I did that.

Comment: Add the
counturl parameter to your twitter widget.     `data-count="http://www.yoursite.com/your/page/"`  See: (https://dev.twitter.com/docs/tweet-button) for more info